# AndroidX Preference library title and summary text sizes

Tags: android, android-settings

I'm using the [Settings library](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings) on my app and since I'm going to creat a very similar screen on my app, I'd like to know what are the sizes of the title and summary textviews to maintain a similar look.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use Android Studio **layout inspector** and check the TextViews font sizes.
You can access the layout inspector by searching for it with "double shift" shortcut.

When you inpect the layout, you will see that the Title is 16sp and the Summary is 14,2sp

Comment: Where is this located ??

Comment: @Noah I improved my answer to explain where you can find it. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: _double shift_, you mean pressing shift twice while using the Android Emulator ?

Comment: @Noah No. It's a shortcut for the Android Studio, not the emulator. This search screen allow you to search for files and Android Studio commands. It does not work on old versions of Android Studio, although I'm not sure exactly in which version it was added.